# Redirigir index a otra pagina dentro del mismo proyecto en GitHub

Tags: javascript, github-pages, index

Lo que quiero hacer es redirigirme desde el Index a otra página que se encuentra dentro del mismo, que debería abrirse a través de un botón, pero al hacer click, abre otra pestaña pero nunca lo encuentra. Soy nuevo subiendo una web por si no se nota, muchas gracias desde ya.

Comment: Hola, haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).